# How to translate the poly-variadic fix-point combinator to a strict language?

Tags: javascript, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, mutual-recursion

I am attempting to translate the following Haskell code to Javascript:

```hs
fix_poly :: [[a] -> a] -> [a]
fix_poly fl = fix (\self -> map ($ self) fl)
  where fix f = f (fix f)
```

I have trouble understanding `($ self)` though. Here is what I've achieved so far:

```js
const structure = type => cons => {
  const f = (f, args) => ({
    ["run" + type]: f,
    [Symbol.toStringTag]: type,
    [Symbol("args")]: args
  });

  return cons(f);
};

const Defer = structure("Defer") (Defer => thunk => Defer(thunk));

const defFix = f => f(Defer(() => defFix(f)));

const defFixPoly = (...fs) =>
  defFix(self => fs.map(f => f(Defer(() => self))));

const pair = defFixPoly(
  f => n => n === 0
    ? true
    : f.runDefer() [1] (n - 1),
  f => n => n === 0
    ? false
    : f.runDefer() [0] (n - 1));

pair[0] (2); // true expected but error is thrown
```

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: f.runDefer(...)[1] is not a function`.

Here is the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413448/5536315).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `defFixPoly` has an extra layer of `Defer` than it should. Since `self` is already a `Defer` value, you can just pass it directly to `f` rather than wrapping it again.

```
const defFixPoly = (...fs) =>
  defFix(self => fs.map(f => f(self)));
```

```js
const structure = type => cons => {
  const f = (f, args) => ({
    ["run" + type]: f,
    [Symbol.toStringTag]: type,
    [Symbol("args")]: args
  });

  return cons(f);
};

const Defer = structure("Defer") (Defer => thunk => Defer(thunk));

const defFix = f => f(Defer(() => defFix(f)));

const defFixPoly = (...fs) =>
  defFix(self => fs.map(f => f(self)));

const pair = defFixPoly(
  f => n => n === 0
    ? true
    : f.runDefer() [1] (n - 1),
  f => n => n === 0
    ? false
    : f.runDefer() [0] (n - 1));

console.log(pair[0] (2)); // true expected
```

This now defines mutually recursive `isEven` and `isOdd` functions.

```
const isEven = pair[0];
const isOdd = pair[1];
```

Comment: This kind of mistakes happen a lot to me, because I tend to focus on patterns (like passing a `Defer` to `f`) rather than actually visualizing the algorithm. This works frequently with the declarative code of FP, but not always.

Comment: @bob, very circular code like this is hard to visualize. Types help a lot. You can use them in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

`($ self)` is just `\f -> f $ self`; it's a function that applies its argument to `self`. You could rewrite the Haskell version using a list comprehension:

```
fix_poly fl = fix (\self -> [f self | f <- fl])
    where fix f = f (fix f)
```